# Clicking a button in IE using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ie-automation

I am using Excel VBA to try click a button on a site, here's the code from the site using inspect element:

```
<button class="_ah57t _84y62 _frcv2 _rmr7s">ClickHere</button>
```

And here's what i'm doing in VBA:

```
Sub testcode()
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "somesite.com"

Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop

Dim e
Set e = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("_ah57t _84y62 _frcv2 _rmr7s")
e.Click

End Sub
```

Using the debug I found that the code seems to be storing something called "[object]" in the variable e and and then gives a Runtime error '438' when it gets to e.click. I have even tried using .Focus first, but get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: No joke, this exact question gets asked at least once every day. Did you look at related questions? Error 438 means `e` doesn't have a `Click` (or `Focus`) method.

Comment: Apologies, as I didn't mean to add to the list of 'similar questions'. I searched the error as well as similar problems but couldn't figure out why it wasn't working...The click method applied to the variable e as you mention wasn't the problem, the problem was as per the bellow answer - the 's' at the end of elements! I think I need to get my eyes checked!!!

Comment: For the record it *was* the problem. `e` being a *collection of elements* means `e` doesn't have a `Click` method. Otherwise you wouldn't have been getting run-time error 438 "Object does not support property or method" - that's what the error message means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975198(v=vs.85).aspx) function returns a collection not a single element. You need to specify an index on the returned collection in order to return a single element. If there is only one element within the class you can simply use:

```
ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("_ah57t _84y62 _frcv2 _rmr7s")(0).Click
```

The `(0)` specifies the index of the element within the collection returned from the class.

Its easy to tell whether a function returns a collection or single element:

- `getElementBy...` - Returns a single element.
- `getElementsBy...` - Returns a collection of elements.

Comment: Thank you so much, my eyesight must be giving in as I looked over this code so many times and only just noticed the 's' after you mentioned it! Feel kinda silly now! Thanks again.

Comment: It's a very common issue! Glad I could help.